# JMS message lost when receiver is not available

Tags: java, jms, messaging, receiver, subscriber

I am using JMS for message passing. And when both sender and receiver available I successfully received the message. But when I down the receiver and start again queued messages are not received to receiver again. Is there any configuration I need to do?
I have increase the time to live as below to avoid expiring the session.

This is how my sender code looks like.

```java
Session session = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Destination destination = session.createTopic(topic);
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
producer.setTimeToLive(18000000L);
TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(customMessage.getContent());
producer.send(message);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're observing is the expected behavior. Since you're sending your message to a JMS *topic* you will be subject to publish/subscribe semantics. Publish/subscribe semantics dictate that messages are only placed in valid subscriptions. When your subscriber is offline it has no valid subscription on the broker to receive the messages therefore it will miss the messages sent to it when it is offline.

You can use a *durable* subscriber to receive messages when the subscriber is offline or you can use a traditional JMS *queue*.

Comment: Will there be impact on this based on "consumer.dispatchAsync=true/false" ?

Comment: No. The value of `consumer.dispatchAsync` will not impact publish/subscribe semantics.

Comment: I checked some of the example on durable subscriber. But in that case subcriber should check " Message message = messageConsumer.receive(timeout);" in order to receive the message. But I am looking where subscriber automatically get the message when start up.

Comment: To understand JMS better you should read the JavaDoc API documentation or the specification instead. Any [`javax.jms.MessageConsumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageConsumer.html) can set a [`javax.jms.MessageListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageListener.html) using the [`setListener()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageConsumer.html#setMessageListener-javax.jms.MessageListener-) method to receive messages automatically and asynchronously. You don't necessarily have to call `receive()` on the `MessageConsumer`.

Comment: I have tried with following https://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-jms-activemq-example. When I start the app again Listener does not get the missing message. What alternation I should do?

Comment: From what I can tell that example uses a **non-durable** topic subscription so once it reconnects it won't receive any of the messages it missed when it was offline. As noted previously, you need to use a **durable** topic subscription or a queue.